# create folder in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have problem let user create folder in laravel 4 through ajax request > route > controller@method.
I did test ajax success request to the url call right method.
When I use `mkdir` or `File::mkdir($path);` (is this method exist?) , I will get the response `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` and fail to create new folder.. how to solve it ?

route.php

```
Route::post('admin/article/addimagegallery', 'AdminDashboardController@addImagegallery');
```

AdminDashboardController

```
public function addImagegallery()
{
    if (Request::ajax())
    {
        …
        $galleryId = 1; // for test
        $path = public_path().'/images/article/imagegallery/'.$galleryId;
        File::mkdir($path);
    }
}
```

js

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'addimagegallery',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {addimagegallery: 'addimagegallery'},
})
.done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: you might be interesting in this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682421/how-to-protect-image-from-public-view-in-laravel-5/30682456#30682456 where you create your images in already writable folder.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

No, actually it's

```
use File;

File::makeDirectory($path);
```

Also, you may try this:

```
$path = public_path().'/images/article/imagegallery/' . $galleryId;
File::makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0777, true, true);
```

**Update:** Actually it does work, `mkdir` is being used behind the scene. This is the source:

```
/**
 * Create a directory.
 *
 * @param  string  $path
 * @param  int     $mode
 * @param  bool    $recursive
 * @param  bool    $force
 * @return bool
 */
public function makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0777, $recursive = false, $force = false)
{
    if ($force)
    {
        return @mkdir($path, $mode, $recursive);
    }
    else
    {
        return mkdir($path, $mode, $recursive);
    }
}
```

**For deleting:**

```
public function deleteDirectory($directory, $preserve = false);
```

Check the source at following path (in your local installation):

> root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php

Comment: wow Thanks so much!! does basic php `mkdir` not work with laravel??  and how to delete folder?   I can't find the document in laravel

Comment: Thanks so much! link is 404  but I find this `https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php`

Comment: Oh no! I meant in your system where the `root` represents the root of of your installation, but you made it anyways, welcome :-)

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha How I can know if the folder exists before creating it?

Comment: How to find this in document?

Comment: @zhelon:

    if ( ! File::exists($path) ) {
      File::makeDirectory($path);
    }

Comment: @TheAlpha: I've tried to create directory in `'public'` folder using above code, but it's not created dir in public folder and also not giving any errors! It's strange!!

Comment: Thanks for the information. It saved me lots of time with my application on Plesk Ubuntu Server but a small advice would be to use 0755 instead of 0777 for web applications.

Comment: yes thank you this is worked for me by 
use File;  $path = 'storage/upload/category/';
        File::makeDirectory($path);

Answer (score 19):

Thanks to The Alpha. Your answer helped me, here is a laravel 5 way to do it for those who use the later version :

```
Storage::disk('local')->makeDirectory('path/to');
```

This will create a directory in `storage/app/path/to`

Retrieve the directory you just created with :

```
storage_path('app/path/to')
```

Comment: Do you know why when the new directory is written on cyrillic, in the filesystem the dir name looks like this: РђРґР»Р»

Comment: @Alex Probably because of font and/or encoding problems. Something along the lines of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16771/foreign-characters-wont-display-in-ssh/16784

Answer (score 9):

There's multiple arguments you can use.

You can create a directory using defaults.

```
$result = File::makeDirectory('/path/to/directory');
```

This will return true if directory was able to be created in the /path/to directory. The file mode of the created directory is 0777.

You can specify the mode.

```
$result = File::makeDirectory('/path/to/directory', 0775);
```

This will return true if directory was able to be created in the /path/to directory. The file mode of the created directory will be 0775.

You can also create the directories recursively.

```
$result = File::makeDirectory('/path/to/directory', 0775, true);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try this code:-

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

if (! File::exists("your-path")) {
    File::makeDirectory("your-path");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for use File this is **use  \Illuminate\Support\Facades\File**