# Laravel doesn't show image

Tags: php, html, laravel, image, laravel-5

I have this in my `view.blade.php`:

```php
{{HTML::image('resources/views/Folder/Subfolder/Subfolder/Photo/'.$item->Photo)}}
```

`$item->Photo` takes the image name from the database.

In the same view I have `use HTML;`, and what I see on the screen is this:

```html
<img src="http://localhost:8000/resources/Folder/Subfolder/Subfolder/Photo/3da0d12d6d8667963392a446262b1773.jpg">
```

If I replace `{{HTML::image....` with the following:

```html
<img src="resources/Folder/Subfolder/Subfolder/Photo/{$item->Photo}}" alt="NO PHOTO">
```

I see this on the screen:

> ```html
> <img src="http://localhost:8000/resources/Folder/Subfolder/Subfolder/Photo/3da0d12d6d8667963392a446262b1773.jpg">
> ```
>
> NO PHOTO

The picture exists, I saw it in the folder. I'm doing something wrong, I just don't know what.

I'm thinking that `Laravel` wants pictures to be in a specific folder... could this be the cause of the problem? Do you have any ideas?

**In my controller I have this:**

```php
$destinationPath = base_path().'\resources\Folder\Subfolder\Subfolder\Photo';
            chmod($destinationPath,0777);
```

The picture size is `7.673 bytes`. I tried it with another image, and it doesn't work either. It seems that something is preventing all browsers from showing the pictures on `localhost`.

Has anyone encountered this problem before ? I don't know what else I should try ...

Comment: did the above image appeared correctly? the one you are showing using laravel

Comment: i see no image, that's the problem

Comment: Debug url of image in your browser, open it in new tab and see if the path is correct.

Comment: I see this in the page source: <img src="http://localhost:8000/Photo/3da0d12d6d8667963392a446262b1773.jpg" >  is that what you want to know >                                                             I made a change, now I have this: {!!HTML::image('Photo/'.$item->Photo, 'NO PHOTO', array( 'width' => 200, 'height' => 200))!!}   and on the screen I see NO PHOTO

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Laravel 5 if you plan to have your images available in public folder, follow this answer:

Create `images` folder under `public` folder in Laravel 5.

Afterward what I do, I use `URL::to('/')` to return base URL, then you can added your images folder location like following example:

```
<img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/{{ $item->Photo }}" alt="{{ $item->Title }}" />
```

OR all of it inside the braces

```
<img src="{{ URL::to('/images/' . $item->Photo) }}" alt="{{ $item->Title }}" />
```

You should not give write permission to resources folder.

`{{ URL::to('/images') }}` generate http://localhost/images in local host environment.

and the folder of images location is: `your_laravel_project/app/public/images`

If you plan to protect your images from public view, so only authenticated user can see the images, then follow this link:

[How to protect image from public view in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682421/how-to-protect-image-from-public-view-in-laravel-5/30682456#30682456)

**Note:** `URL::to('/')` returns base URL and it can be used different ways. [Here](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Contracts/Routing/UrlGenerator.html#method_to) you can find in depth info about it.

Reference: http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Contracts/Routing/UrlGenerator.html#method_to

Comment: This is what I was looking for... i just want to know what URL::to('/') does ?

Comment: Didnt you advice me on another question to place images in the resources folder ?

Comment: @svenb I saw your question and I do not  advice you that, I suggest you to protect your images folder but you wanted to find the permission problem, which is fair. If the answer here can be used in your case I will be happy, if not then I think the problem you have had in your question is possible not the same as here. I wanted earlier only to help you with other solution. let me know it is still so I can look at it.

Comment: how to use in css?

Answer (score 2):

```
{{ asset("storage/uploads/$notes->file_name")}}
```

this worked for me. i had file in uploads of storage/app/public folder. tried so many things. turns out its little confusing but awesomely simple once u figure it out. i am in laravel 5.4

Answer (score 0):

Show image Laravel 5 if you plan to have your images available in public folder. To display images folder under public folder in Laravel 5 simple:

```
<img class="img-responsive menu-thumbnails" src="{{ asset($item->photo) }}"/>
```