# Laravel "Can't write image data to path" error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, intervention

I am currently using the Intervention Image package within Laravel.

I am wanting a user to have the ability to upload a logo. So far, I have the following:

```
public function postUpdateLogo($id) {

    if(Input::file())
    {

        $image = Input::file('logo');
        $filename  = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        \Image::make($image->getRealPath())
                  ->resize(300, 300)
                  ->save('user/'. $id . '/' . $filename);
        $user->image = $filename;
        $user->save();
    }
}
```

But the error I'm getting upon submission is:

> NotWritableException in Image.php line 143: Can't write image data to
>   path (user/1/1439491280.png)

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like the directory you're trying to save to isn't writable (`777`).

Comment: It also looks like you'll probably want to add some more info to the path, e.g. `'/path/to/images/user/'.$id. ...`

Comment: @JoelHinz, the `user/$id/randomString` would suffice I think? I don't think that's causing the problem though.

Comment: Well, yes, if you're trying to upload it to Laravel's root folder. Don't you want to put it in the public folder at least?

Comment: I thought that would default into the public directory? My intention was to put it in there though!

Comment: Based on the [Intervention docs](http://image.intervention.io/), it looks like you'll need to save to `public/user/...`.

Comment: In that case, should be easy to fix the path: `->save(public_path('user/' . $id ...));` - of course, that's assuming the folder exists and is writable. :)

Comment: check those for inspiration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682421/how-to-protect-image-from-public-view-in-laravel-5/30682456#30682456 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582829/laravel-doesnt-show-image/31584676#31584676

Comment: Btw I do not suggest giving write permission to public folder, you can follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682421/how-to-protect-image-from-public-view-in-laravel-5/30682456#30682456 to upload image, and if you want to make them public, then just remove 'middleware' => 'auth',

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem too, as Stuard suggested you might want to write in the public folder.

```
$filename  = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$path = public_path("user/".$id."/".$filename);

\Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(300, 300)->save($path);
```

Secondly I managed to fix my problem (ubuntu, apache, laravel 5 setup) by making apache the owner of that public folder e.g. :

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/youruser/www/dev.site.com/public/user
```

add the right folder permission:

```
~$ sudo chmod 755 -R user
```

Might not be a perfect solution but will get you going.

Edit - a possible second option:

Checking the current group owner of your public folder and then adding apache user (www-data) to that group might be a second option (hope the gurus agree):

```
sudo adduser www-data theownergroup
```