# Laravel Crud image wont show

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a user panel in laravel. Here i also want to upload a profile picture. I store the picture in (projectname)/public/storage/profilepicture/(image)
but it wont load in my blade file.

```
  <td><img src="/public/storage/profilepicture/{{$user->picture}}" width="100px"/> </td>
```

i used this line but it wont show up

Comment: check this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582829/laravel-doesnt-show-image

maybe it'll help you to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you created a storage symlink? ```php artisan storage:link```

Comment: Have you linked your storage? If not run `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: please check the error on `console.log` and compare the path showing in console with the actual path, then you could find the issue.

Comment: ooh i fixed it, i had a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// I am using this code to load the image in my blade file

{{ asset('storage/profilepicture/'.$user->profilepicture) }}

// But it wont load. I am using this code to store the image in my controller

$user->profilepicture = $request->file('profilepicture')->store('profilepicture');

// I am using this code to store the image in my model

public function getProfilepictureAttribute($value)
{
    return asset('storage/'.$value);
}

// I am using this code to store the image in my blade file

{{ $user->profilepicture }}

// I am using this code to store the image in my blade file

{{ asset('storage/'.$user->profilepicture) }}

// I am using this code to store the image in my blade file

{{ asset('storage/profilepicture/'.$user->profilepicture) }}
```