# Laravel 5: FineUploader - Uploads directory isn't writable

Tags: php, laravel-5, fine-uploader

I am working with Laravel 5 and I am trying to use FineUploder.
Here is what I used

[PHP-Traditional](https://github.com/FineUploader/php-traditional-server)

First I was having **VerifyCsrfToken** error and as a temporary commented out

```
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

**From**

```
App/Http/Kernel.php
```

CsrfToken error gone!

Now I am having "**Uploads directory isn't writable**" error.

**My Route**

```
Route::resource('endpoint','FineUploaderController');
```

**My FineUploaderController**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     // dd('store');
     return view('fineupload.endpoint');
}
```

**My upload Folder inside public folder**

```
/uploads/receiptuploads
```

**And endpoint.php**

```
if ($method == "POST") {
header("Content-Type: text/plain");

// Assumes you have a chunking.success.endpoint set to point here with a query parameter of "done".
// For example: /myserver/handlers/endpoint.php?done
if (isset($_GET["done"])) {
    $result = $uploader->combineChunks("/uploads/receiptuploads");
}
// Handles upload requests
else {
    // Call handleUpload() with the name of the folder, relative to PHP's getcwd()
    $result = $uploader->handleUpload("/uploads/receiptuploads");

    // To return a name used for uploaded file you can use the following line.
    $result["uploadName"] = $uploader->getUploadName();
}

echo json_encode($result);
}
// for delete file requests
else if ($method == "DELETE") {
    $result = $uploader->handleDelete("/uploads/receiptuploads");
    echo json_encode($result);
}
else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed");
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the chmod of the uploads directory to something like 0755?

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois I have tried but still same! (eg. 777)

Comment: Have you restarted the web server after that?

Comment: I am working locally using MAMP

Comment: Another way is to upload your files in a writable area like inside storage folder at the same time possible to protect image if required, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682421/how-to-protect-image-from-public-view-in-laravel-5/30682456#30682456 if you do not want to protect files just remove the authentication from the route.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: you will need to make the "/uploads" directory writeable for whatever user is running the PHP server. If you have attempted to do this and are stuck with the same result, you have most definitely either assigned the wrong permissions, or are targeting the wrong directory.

Note that you will need to do the same for whichever directory is configured to temporary store file chunks.

Comment: Thanks  for your reply. How can I confirm that I am targeting right directory? is there any way to find out path?