# Laravel 5 template storage directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 4 my `public` directory is my template storage such as `images` and `css`, `js` folder, what's this storage in Laravel 5? How do I store files in the new version using `asset()` to access them?

Comment: There's a `public` folder in Laravel 5, that hasn't changed between the two versions.

Comment: Laravel 5 has also public folder, but it has also a place called storage and resources. Resouces is for your templates etc files, Storage is writable folder for logs etc. and public is for all public content. If you have important content you want only share with you members you can save those on Storage and Show only to specific users or members. http://laravel.com/docs/master/structure#the-root-directory

Comment: If that does not cover what you asked for, let us know

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ thanks sir, i'm understand me

Comment: @mahdipishguy you are welcome dude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 folders which are relevant to your questions.

They are place in **The Root Directory**.

Regarding to Laravel [The Root Directory documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/master/structure#the-root-directory):

- The `public` directory contains the front controller and your assets (images, JavaScript, CSS, etc.).
- The `resources` directory contains your views, raw assets (LESS, SASS, CoffeeScript), and localization files.
- The `storage` directory contains compiled Blade templates, file based sessions, file caches, and other files generated by the framework. This folder is segregated into app, framework, and logs directories. The app directory may be used to store any files utilized by your application. The framework directory is used to store framework generated files and caches. Finally, the logs directory contains your application's log files.

It is possible to create a content folder in Storage folder and share it only for members (means no available for public access), if that the case follow example link below.

To define path in your code, for public path use `public_path` the same for storage `storage_path` regarding to Laravel [Paths documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#paths).

Finally here you find the example of `storage_path` usage and how you protect you files and folders from public access.

[How to protect image from public view in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682421/how-to-protect-image-from-public-view-in-laravel-5/30682456#30682456)