# Protect Images from being public laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i have seen certain techniques to protect images like to show them only to authenticated users. one example is

[how-to-protect-image-from-public-view-in-laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682421/how-to-protect-image-from-public-view-in-laravel-5#)

It tells us only about 1 image. what if we want to retrieve multiple private images and show them to authenticated users?. What is the most appropriate way?. we cannot generate a link to storage directory right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the images in your storage folder which isn't publicly accessible. Then create a route to generate the image based on the parameter, which could be the image name or path. Wrap this route with the `auth` middleware. Display the image content with appropriate headers in the controller method for the route based on its parameters.

Edit : Check this out to give you an idea.

Sample route

```
Route::get('securedimage/{name}', 'SecuredImageController@show');
```

Sample controller method

```
public function show($name)
{
    // check if the image with name exists in the folder that you store them
    // If the image doesn't exist then display dummy image or return nothing
    $imagePath = storage_path('/upload/' . $name);

    return Image::make($imagePath)->response();
}
```

Then you can access images like so

```
<img src="http://example.com/securedimage/ball.jpg">
<img src="http://example.com/securedimage/topsecret.jpg">
```

Comment: what if i want to show multiple images and not a single image

Comment: It doesn't matter how many images. When you link to the image in your html or directly, it's gonna hit your route to fetch the image and not your image resource directly.

Comment: the link i just mentioned tells us how to make an image instance to use it inside the html file. if i have lets say 20 different protect images to display on a single page, would i have to write that last line 20 times??? please explain the whole process

Comment: @AhmedKhan updated my answer to give u an idea of what i'm talking about

Comment: That is fantastic. Thanku so much

Comment: When i go to import a class, I get 7 different options. Would you give more specifics on your Image class?

`Faker\Provider\Image;`
`Nette\Utils\Image;`
`Svg\Tag\Image;`
`League\CommonMark\Extension\CommonMark\Node\Inline\Image;`
`Dompdf\Renderer\Image;` 
`Dompdf\FrameReflower\Image;` 
`Dompdf\FrameDecorator\Image;`

Comment: This does not appear to work in Laravel 9