# Secure a public folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a Web site created by Laravel 4. My Web site got hacked three times when I check my *file.log*.

I found the hacker upload *file.txt* on the *public* folder and after change the extension to *.php* and upload another files. I need help how I can secure my *public* folder.

Comment: Please follow this link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682421/how-to-protect-image-from-public-view-in-laravel-5)

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd that link has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @Don'tPanic How?

Comment: @Don'tPanic In this link suggest store files/images are store in storage folder

Comment: How what? The link you posted is about hiding content in public/ from visibility.  This question has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Have you tried limiting the extension/files that are allowed when uploading?

Comment: What do you see in file.log?