# Laravel keep image private to auth user

Tags: php, laravel, authorization

Picture this...
I have a webapp (built in Laravel) where users can login and upload their favourite pictures.
I want only the authenticated user (the person who logged in and uploaded the image) to be able to view/edit the image.
I have searched the web but cannot find a decent answer explaining how to do this.
I've tried a few solutions but the image is accessible via eg
http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/my-images/1/15.jpeg
/1/  being the user id of logged in user.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Now if you want to include the image in the browser's rendering of the page, the browser will have to ask your server for the image through an <img> tag... For this image to be displayable to the user, it must be accessible somehow... There is no difference between the <img> tag accessing the url and you typing that url address manually...

Comment: Mind you, if you are dead set on doing this, you could decide to serve the image yourself... now this will require that you handle the image file request through Laravel as well... returning the image only if the user is authenticated... Take a look at this answer which shows you how... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682421/how-to-protect-image-from-public-view-in-laravel-5/30682456#30682456

Comment: This somewhat older thread (with code examples) may also be helpful: https://laravel.io/forum/04-23-2015-securing-filesimages. It boils down to *not* storing images in the public folder, building a custom route for images and protecting that route with auth middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution that comes to my mind is comparing the authenticated user id with the author of the photo. E.g. assuming that you have a column (property) identifying the author of the photo in your Photo model, you could do this:

```
Auth::user()->id == $photo->user_id
```

You can easily test how it works even in your blade templates and then move it to a controller. The key here is the Auth facade, through which you can get the currently authenticated user.

If you want something cleaner, you may look into gates and policies. They are covered in the [Authorization section of Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization).

Comment: the problem is with these solutions is that you can still browse to the file if you know the location. Thanks for the help tho guys.

Comment: You won't be able to see them if you go ahead with the solution from here: https://laravel.io/forum/04-23-2015-securing-filesimages.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the link. OK so I can secure the image from being browsed to.  Will it matter if I have made a sym link from public to storage?  I also cannot display it in my blade file now?  Can you explain how i view the image?

Comment: I am quite sure you shouldn't symlink from public to the folder you want to protect. If you have a symlink from public/storate to storage/app/public, but place your 'protected' images in storage/app/private you should be fine, though. To include a protected image in your blade views, you simply reference the image in a regular html image tag. Just copy the code the FileController code from the first answer in the thread I linked, and 1 line of code to your routes. You may need to implement your own version of the storage_path() function, or just hardcode the path to storage/app/private.