# Storage laravel. Is this secure to keep private image?

Tags: laravel

Hi i'm working on sell picture project. I want to secure image in public folder . I follow this way [How to protect image from public view in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682421/how-to-protect-image-from-public-view-in-laravel-5)

Everything work fine. I just want to make sure in storage Path thier is no way to access with URL right? I put my image into storage/images  not storage/app/public

If i storage link it will be effect to my private image or not thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Laravel the root of the webserver is the `public` directory and the entrypoint is `public/index.php`.

This means that you can access via web server everything under `public` directory (like javascript/css files and image assets).

The `storage` directory is one level up and there is no way to access it.

In the discussion you mention the url `http://www.somedomainname.net/images/users/userImage.jpg` refers to the file `userImage.jpg` under `/your/document/root/laravel/app/public/images/users` by default, so the `storage` directory is not even read.

Laravel, though, will let you link the `storage/app/public` directory inside the `public/storage` directory, using the command `php artisan storage:link`, but that's it.

Comment: Now I keep image in storage folder and manage it in controller  thabk you for info