# How to access a folder from a different URL?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, directory

I have a folder named /admin/ in public which I can currently access through domain.com/admin/.
How can I change the URL so I can access the folder from domain.com/very/secret/folder/ instead for example. (Without actually having to create the directories very, secret and folder)
I believe this should be possible with using an Alias but I get an internal server error whenever I try.

Comment: that may help you .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682421/how-to-protect-image-from-public-view-in-laravel-5

Comment: You need to provide a minimal code to reproduce the problem. See more details on how to post a question at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You would do this in routes. In routes/web.php you can enter something like:

```
Route::get('/very/secret/folder', function() {

    return view('secret');

});
```

This would return the view secret.blade.php. You can also do things like this:

```
Route::get('/very/secret/folder', 'SecretController@index');
```

This would call the index() method in SecretController where you can serve your view and do other things, like send data from your model.