# Laravel Storage Private Image Access

Tags: laravel

I am trying to access images outside the public folder in storage from the view. I can get the images in the storage/app/public folder like this

```
    <img src="storage/imagename.jpg" height="200" width="200">
```

I have an avatar folder inside storage/app/avatar , how do I get it to the view

Comment: Did you run `php artisan storage:link` to create a symlink between `storage/public` to `public/storage` ?

Comment: Hi sorry my question was not clear I think. I can access public folder inside the storage/app/public and it is working. I do have a private folder named avatar inside storage/app/avatar , how do I access that one ? And yes I run php artisan storage:link

Answer (score 0):

In your `config/filesystems.php` in the `links` attribute add the followig:

```php
'links' => [
    ...
    public_path('avatars') => storage_path('app/avatar'),
],
```

Then run `php artisan storage:link` to create the link.

Access it like so:

```html
<img src="avatars/1.jpg">
```

Or better use the [asset](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-asset) method

```html
<img src="{{ asset('avatars/1.jpg`) }}">
```

Comment: Hi sorry my question was not clear I think. I can access public folder inside the storage/app/public and it is working. I do have a private folder named avatar inside storage/app/avatar , how do I access that one ? The above solution you provided is for the public folder

Comment: I have updated my answer it will create a symbolic link in your public folder linking to  your avatar folder so you can access it

Comment: But I do not want general public access the images from the avatar folder, it should only be available for logged in users. Do the above answer you provided make avatar publicly visible ?

Comment: It does not. your question was not so clear but here is a [possible solotuin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30682456/11801683)

Comment: @rahulvimal were you able to solve it , the solution provider by jewishmoses is not for s3 bucket