# How to Unauthorized user can not access Image URL from Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I Have a laravel project with API. Now I want to integrate image protection like if users login then that user image url can access otherwise not.

If Any Users can copy URL and past in image url in the browser then if users have login with My web then see my images otherwise user can not see my images.

I have flow below reference URL and tried to implement and I have to get a blob URL and that accessible in the google viewer but this three extension png, jpeg, and PDF but the other extension for Word files like doc, Docx, dot, and dots, etc can not work. getting error and preview that.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682421/how-to-protect-image-from-public-view-in-laravel-5#:~:text=Create%20Route,person%20is%20not%20logged%20in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682421/how-to-protect-image-from-public-view-in-laravel-5#:%7E:text=Create%20Route,person%20is%20not%20logged%20in)

Anyone have any idea about laravel, PHP then please guide us.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to protect image from public view in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682421/how-to-protect-image-from-public-view-in-laravel-5)

Comment: @NicoHaase I have already shared that  link in my comment that not work properly in in doc file

Comment: If that does not work, please share more details, like the configuration and code involved