# Checking folder already existed and if not create a new folder by id in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i want to store my image to a specific folder and the folder will named by page id. For example if Page id=1, the folder location should be public/pages/page_id/image_here.

If the folder are not existed yet the system will generate and named with their page id.

```
 $id=1;
 $directoryPath=public_path('pages/' . $id);

if(File::isDirectory($directoryPath)){
        //Perform storing
    } else {
        Storage::makeDirectory($directoryPath);
        //Perform storing
    }
```

But i having error that "mkdir(): Invalid argument". 
Can i know why it happen?

And after my research some people say the folder name should based with id+token so intruder cannot search image based on id, is there possible to achieve?

Comment: in your else condition just use File::makeDirectory instande of Storage::makeDirectory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create folder in laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869223/create-folder-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `Storage` facade, it uses `local` disk as default which is configured to work with `storage_path()`.

So, if you want to create directory in `public` directory, use `File::makeDirectory` which is just simple wrapper for `mkdir()` with additional options or use `mkdir()` directly:

```
File::makeDirectory($directoryPath);
mkdir($directoryPath);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but when I use `File` instead of `Storage` it works!

```php
$id=1;
$directoryPath=public_path('pages/'.$id);

//check if the directory exists
if(!File::isDirectory($directoryPath)){
    //make the directory because it doesn't exists
    File::makeDirectory($directoryPath);
}

//Perform store of the file
```

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

```
For basic Laravel file system the syntax is :
At very top under namespace write:
use File;

Then in your method use:

$id=1;
$directoryPath=public_path('pages/' . $id);

if(File::isDirectory($directoryPath)){
    //Perform storing
} else {

    File::makeDirectory($directoryPath, 0777, true, true);
    //Perform storing
}
```