# Laravel making directory in Storage path return TRUE but i dont have directory into that

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

in Storage directory of `laravel` structure i have download directory and i want to create directory into that by this code:

```
Storage::makeDirectory("downloads/"."test")
```

that return `true`, now after reload storage directory i dont have test directory into downloads

i test this code again but i have this problem too

```
Storage::makeDirectory("test")
```

i check permission storage folder and other things that i think about them

Comment: I think this question will help you , At stack over flow [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869223/create-folder-in-laravel/49475111)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your file system you have added proper disks. you can find file system config at `App\config\filesystem.php`

> **CHECK `public\` directory not `App\Storage`**

For more info : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem