# How to create a folder in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, directory

laravel version  6.18.8

i used this line to make a directory but it say **Method Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::mkdir does not exist.**

```
$newDirectory = public_path() . 'img/reviews/' . Str::slug($request->title,'-');
File::mkdir($newDirectory);
```

i also used **makeDirectory()** that was also not working..

please help to make a directory using laravel

Comment: have you tried `composer dump-autoload`? also you can use `Storage::makeDirectory($directory);` to create directory

Comment: `composer dump-autoload`  `Storage::makeDirectory($directory);` 
those both command have to use or dump load for File package?

Comment: doesn't work this

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` is to regenerate your autoloader file. A quick fix would be to delete your vendor folder and run the `composer install ` again and generate all the vendors back.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create folder in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869223/create-folder-in-laravel)

Comment: it doesn't work. don't know why

Answer (score 0):

You may use php `mkdir` function

```
$dirPath = public_path('img/reviews/' . Str::slug($request->title,'-')); 
if (!file_exists($dirPath)) {
    mkdir($dirPath, 0777, true);
}
```

See [How to create directory if not exists in Laravel 7.x and 6.x?](https://hdtuto.com/article/how-to-create-directory-if-not-exists-in-laravel-6)

Comment: well this would work but will not fix the OP's problem

Comment: Well, behind the scenes Laravel also uses php native functions. right ?

Comment: Yes it does uses this behind the scene but Laravel offers way too much feature through `Filesystem` if that is broken then the whole app might break.

Comment: I guess the OP mis-typed or imported the `File` Facade

Comment: can you please help me with another topic?
I used this code for single upload.

**if (request()->has('image')) {
    $photo = request()->file('image');
    $image = Image::make($request->image);
    $image->save(public_path('../../img/galleries/gallery-images/' . DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId() . '.png'));

    DB::table('galleries')
        ->where('id', '=', DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId())
        ->update([
            'image' => DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId() . '.png',
        ]);
}**
but how can i use it in multiple upload